# Internal pool and external pool usage

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I develop non-JAVA EE application. From [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/concepts/data_access006.htm#CHDHEIJE)

> For non-Java EE applications, you typically use internal connection
>   pools. By default, EclipseLink sessions use internal connection pools.

Besides I don't configure connection pool in persistence.xml. However in `org.eclipse.persistence.core.log` I see the following:

```
TRACE | Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
TRACE | reconnecting to external connection pool
DEBUG | SELECT * FROM test
TRACE | Connection released to connection pool [read].
```

Please, note `reconnecting to external connection pool`. Why external? How to explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem. In order to make EclipseLink use internal pool we must set in persistence.xml

```
<property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.force-internal-pool" value="true"/>
```

Hope it will save someone time.